# overflow-wrap not breaking word on dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Ingredients for a recipe are dynamically added to a div from an API Ajax call. Each line of text stays on one line, meaning its not breaking and wrapping to the line below. I have tried word-break and overflow-wrap added through a CSS styled class and then adding the class dynamically. I am getting no change. Incidentally, my bullet points wont show up in front of each ingredient line either.

I do have a CSS reset stylesheet attached and linked above my main CSS stylesheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvuRi.jpg - screenshot

JavaScript

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

function recipeSearch(foodtype){
var searchTerm = $(this).attr("data-name");
var queryURL = "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=" + foodtype + "&app_id=c13467eb&app_key=9cd5b15a4c49f23093c8fe1f1d2c7ce4"

$.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);


        for (var k = 0; k<10; k++){
            var foodDiv = $("<div class = 'recipeCard'>");


                if (response.hits.length === 0) {
                    $("#recipeOutput").append("<p>" + "Please enter valid recipe ingredient or name." + "</p>");
                };

            var recipeName = response.hits[k].recipe.label;
            var pOne = $("<p>").html("<h2>" + recipeName + "</h2>");
            foodDiv.append(pOne);

            var recipePic = response.hits[k].recipe.image;
            var pTwo = $("<img class='recipeImage'>").attr("src", recipePic);
            foodDiv.append(pTwo);

            var recipeURL = response.hits[k].recipe.shareAs;
            var pThree =$("<p>").html("<a target='_blank' href='" + recipeURL + "'>" + "Get full recipe here" + "</a>");
            foodDiv.append(pThree);

            var length = response.hits[k].recipe.ingredients.length;

            var ingList = $("<ul>");
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){

                var ing = response.hits[k].recipe.ingredients[i].text;
                var pFour = $("<li class='loopText wordBreak'>").text(ing);
                ingList.append(pFour);
            };
            foodDiv.append(ingList);

            var health = response.hits[k].recipe.healthLabels;
            var pFive = $("<p>").text(health);
            foodDiv.append(pFive);

            $("#recipeOutput").append(foodDiv);
        }

    });
};


function clear(){
    $("#recipeOutput").empty();
}

$("#recipeSearch").on("click", function(event){
   var foodtype = $("#recipeInput").val().trim();
   clear();
   recipeSearch(foodtype);
   return false;
});
});

$("#recipeInput").keyup(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $("#recipeSearch").click();
}
});
```

CSS

```
li.loopText {
    display: block;
    overflow-wrap: break-all;
    padding: 2px;
    margin 1px auto;
    list-style-type: circle;
}
label {
    color: white;
}
wordBreak {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="col s12 m12 l6 xl6">
            <div class=" panel-boxes">
                <div class="panel-heading">WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO COOK?</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipeInput">
                        <button type="search" class="btn" id="recipeSearch" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 15px">Search</button>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="panel-body recipesContainer" id="recipeOutput" ></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Very difficult to help CSS problems without having a working page. Can you link to a Codepen or somewhere else the site is hosted?

Comment: https://wbwelch.github.io/DayTripper/stayin.html Will this suffice?

Comment: I'm seeing some js errors - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipe' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `li {white-space: normal;}` for the list items.

That seems to work for me in Chrome and Safari.
Alternatively, use `ul {white-space: normal;}` for the whole **ul**, and all the list items will inherit it.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!